# How to test if a string contains more than N nested function calls?

Tags: python, string

There is a set of strings that represents a list of nested function calls:

```
# (string, number of nested calls)
tests = [('f1(p1)', 0), ('f1(f2(p1, p2))', 1), ('f1(p1, f2(p2, f3(f4(p1), p2), p1)', 3)]
```

How to write a function to test if a string contains more than N nested function calls?

Only valid functions calls.

Comment: A regex is not recursive by default. You can't. Either way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: you are right, my mistake. I have fixed the question

Comment: Can parentheses be used for anything *other* than function calls?

Comment: only functions call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct nested braces is a [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language).

[image]

Working code:

```
tests = [('f1(p1)', 0), ('f1(f2(p1, p2))', 1), ('f1(p1, f2(p2, f3(f4(p1), p2), p1)', 3),
         ('f(f(p), f(f(p), f(f(p), f(f(p, p), p), p), p), p)', 4),
         ('f(f(p, p), f(p, f(p, p, p), p), f(p, p))', 2)]

for node, d in tests:
  print('--------')
  print(node, d)
  
  current_nesting = 0
  max_depth = 0
  for s in node:
    if s == '(':
      current_nesting += 1
    elif s == ')':
      current_nesting -= 1
    if current_nesting > max_depth:
      max_depth = current_nesting

  print('max_depth', max_depth, max_depth-1==d)
```

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is that you need a full language tokenizer to handle all cases of parsing function calls where `(` and `)` may be inside strings or tuples and newlines or whitespace may split things in weird ways.

For fun.. parsing just your well-formed examples, count the opening parentheses `(` before any closing `)` ones.

```
tests = [('f1(p1)', 0), ('f1(f2(p1, p2))', 1), ('f1(p1, f2(p2, f3(f4(p1), p2), p1)', 3)]

N = 2
for ts,tn in tests:
    for s in ts.split(')'):
        if s.count('(') > N:
            print(ts, 'has more than', N, 'nested funcs')
```

Outputs the last expression.

Comment: Code does not work for:
`str1 = 'f(f(p), f(f(p), f(f(p), f(f(p, p), p), p), p), p)'
str2 = 'f(f(p, p), f(p, f(p, p, p), p), f(p, p))'`